# Handling Option[A] in a function

Tags: scala, scala-2.11

I need a function which does something like the code below

```
def function[A,B](a: Option[A], f: Function[A,B]) = {
        a match {
          case None => None
          case Some(v) => Some(f(v))
        }
      }
```

Is there any scala built-in function which does the same?

Comment: `Option.map`? It looks like the `Some` case should return `Some(f(v))`?

Comment: Yes, that's right it should be Some(f(v))

Comment: A nice way to understand the built-in `Option` methods is [Tony Morris' Option Cheat Sheet](http://tonymorris.github.io/blog/posts/scalaoption-cheat-sheet/).

Comment: Lee got the point because I don't event need the function :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def function[A,B](a: Option[A], f: Function[A,B]) = {
  a.map(f(_))
}
```

Option can be treated as a Monad so many operations such as `map`, `flatMap`, and `filter` are available on it.

http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Option

Comment: even shorter: `def function[A,B](a: Option[A], f: A => B) = a.map(f)`

Comment: I need the side effect as well. Not working with function(Some("test"),println)

Comment: @stsatlantis, I just tried in the REPL and it works as expected. If you pass `println` it prints `"test"` and it returns an `Option[Unit]`